# Proof by induction: Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

Given the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, I want to prove that $A^k = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2k \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ (**=induction hypothesis**). Since I struggled a bit with induction in the past, I want to know if I did this correctly:

$A^1 $ is clear.

$A^{k+1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2(k+1)\ \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2k \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ with **induction hypothesis**: $ A^{k+1} = A^k \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ which is basically what we are looking for.

Comment: You want matrix *multiplication*, not addition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must assume truth for $\;k\;$ , i.e.:

$$A^k=\begin{pmatrix}1&2k\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

and under this assumption prove for $\;k+1\;$ , **but**

$$A^{k+1}=\color{red}{A^k}A\stackrel{\color{red}{\text{Ind. Hypothesis}}}=\color{red}{\begin{pmatrix}1&2k\\0&1\end{pmatrix}}\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Now carry on the easy matrix product on the right and verify you get what you need.

Comment: yes of course matrix multiplication, it was just a typo

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ It is the special case $\ a_j = 2\ $ of the following

$$ \left[\begin{matrix} 1  & a_{k+1} \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix} 0  & a_1+\cdots+a_{k} \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right] \,=\,  \left[\begin{matrix} 1  & a_1+\cdots+a_{k+1} \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]\qquad\ $$

$$\Rightarrow\quad {\Large \prod_{j=1}^k}  \left[\begin{matrix} 1  & a_{j} \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]\,=\, \left[\begin{matrix} 1  & \sum_{j=1}^k a_{j} \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right] $$

Comment: This might involve a bit more than you know, but you may find it instructive to gain some insight as to what sort of arithmetic is at the heart of the induction. In particular, to make this rigorous you also need to know rigorous (recursive) definitions of the sums and products used above (including the sum informally denoted by the ellipses).